# Apache Camel - Connect to Gtalk

Tags: apache-camel, google-talk

I trying to use apache camel to send instant message using gtalk account.

I used apache camel xmpp component. I was able to connect to my jabber account and send message successfully. For jabber account, i am using the following url

xmpp://abc@jabber.org/praveen@gmail.com?password=secret"

This sends a message from my abc jabber account to praveen gmail account. But when i try to send message from my gmail account it fails with the below exception

xmpp://talk.google.com:5222/abc@jabber.org?serviceName=gmail.com&user=praveen&password=secret

```
Caused by: SASL authentication PLAIN failed: invalid-authzid: 
at org.jivesoftware.smack.SASLAuthentication.authenticate(SASLAuthentication.java:337)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.login(XMPPConnection.java:203)
at org.apache.camel.component.xmpp.XmppEndpoint.createConnection(XmppEndpoint.java:169)
at org.apache.camel.component.xmpp.XmppPrivateChatProducer.doStart(XmppPrivateChatProducer.java:105)
at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:60)
at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:62)
at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.doGetProducer(ProducerCache.java:387)
... 7 more
```

When i did some research on this, i found Google doesn't support SASL. so i need to set

```
setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(false);
```

on org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration to get it working. But i could not find any parameter in camel docs to set this parameter.

Has anyone successfully done this? If yes, can you please provide me some info about this?

Thanks,
Palanivel Rajan B

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the source, there seems to be no way to do this with the current implementation.

```
if (port > 0) {
        if (getServiceName() == null) {
            connection = new XMPPConnection(new ConnectionConfiguration(host, port));
        } else {
            connection = new XMPPConnection(new ConnectionConfiguration(host, port, serviceName));
        }
    } else {
        connection = new XMPPConnection(host);
    }
```

It should not be hard to either add this feature to the XMPP component (and you might want to add a patch for that in such case, so it might get into future versions of camel) or you could derive from the XmppEndpoint class and override the createConnection method. You might need to override some other classes in the XMPP component to make sure your custom endpoint is used instead of the original one.

Comment: Thanks petter. I will submit a patch to the apache camel team.

Comment: Yeah we love contributions and patches. You can read a bit about how to contribute here: http://camel.apache.org/contributing.html